# Parsing JSON response as a variable to handlebars view in node.js / express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'm looking for a way to render a view that will have a variable containing data fetched from the API. I'm using express, handlebars and request.

Here's the web-server's router code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

router.get('/projects', (req, res) => {
    request('http://localhost:8080/NpZke93tNYf9eR07fIDm/reports/projects', (error, response, body) => {
        res.render('projectsPage', {projects: JSON.stringify(response.body)});
    })
});
// returns:
// {"data":[{"project":"project 1","details":"details of project 1"},{"project":"project 2","details":"some other details"}],"message":"ok","code":200}
```

And here's the handlebars view's code (projectsPage.hbs):

```
<h1>Available Projects</h1>
<script>
    var myData = "{{projects}}";
</script>
```

The problem is that my when the view's rendered, the myData variable contains content that canot be parsed by JSON.parse().

```
>myVar
"&quot;{&quot;data&quot;:[{&quot;project&quot;:&quot;project 1&quot;,&quot;details&quot;:&quot;details of project 1&quot;},{&quot;project&quot;:&quot;project 2&quot;,&quot;details&quot;:&quot;some other details&quot;}],&quot;message&quot;:&quot;ok&quot;,&quot;code&quot;:200}&quot;"
```

What I'm trying to do is to render a page which will present the data using Chart.js (that's why I need to have the data available as an object). I don't want to make direct calls to the API from the front-end (to not expose api key).

Is there a way to make it work without having to use String.replace() method? Is my approach valid or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<h1>Available Projects</h1>
<script>
    var myData = "{{projects}}";
</script>
```

to

```
<h1>Available Projects</h1>
<script>
    var myData = {{{projects}}}
</script>
```

When you are creating Chart instance on Javascript, use the following:

```
data: JSON.parse(myData),
```